# Python Socket transfer speed too low

Tags: android, python, sockets, accelerometer

I'm running Python on my Android 2.3 powered HTC phone using SL4A ... so I wrote a code to retrieve accelerometer values and send them to my pc via Sockets ! The problem is that on phone the code gets values each 100ms and I'm using a while loop to keep sending them to PC. But the pc doesn't get the values at the same speed, I mean it's slower, and just to keep in mind that I modified the values to be like so :

```
> [0.0,1.0,-5.0]
> [0.0,2.0,-2.0] a list of Rounded floats
> ...
```

and here is my server code (running on pc):

```
import socket

HOST = ""            
PORT = 55600             
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    if not data: break
conn.close()
```

Any help to make it faster ?

Comment: This question cannot be answered without additional information. What do you mean by slower? 100.01ms intervals are slower than 100ms ones, but fully expected due to network latency. Also, can you post the program you're using to *send* the values? To debug the problem, you should also include a timestamp of the device-local time in each message so that you can exclude scheduler problems.

Comment: Hey Phihag ! 1st thnx for ur cmmnt ! so what I meant was that the PC is receiving the values too slowly, and sometimes ignoring someones ! I think it's a connection problem, maybe a transfer speed should be modified or another connection protocol to be used !

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would change is getting rid of the print statement in your loop.  IO is very slow.  This is, of course, assuming you're planning on doing something with these values besides display them to the screen ;)

Comment: Sorry bro ! this isn't the case ! I already tried it ... but nothing interesting ...